# Find file names in other Bash files using grep

Tags: bash, file, unix, grep, output

How do I loop through a list of Bash file names from an input text file and grep each file in a directory for each file name (to see if the file name is contained in the file) and output to text all file names that weren't found in any files?

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script will be used to output any unreferenced bash files
# included in the WebAMS Project
# Read file path of bash files and file name input

SEARCH_DIR=$(awk -F "=" '/Bash Dir/ {print $2}' bash_input.txt)
FILE_NAME=$(awk -F "=" '/Input File/ {print $2}' bash_input.txt)

echo $SEARCH_DIR
echo $FILE_NAME

exec<$FILE_NAME

while read line
do
    echo "IN WHILE"
    if (-z "$(grep -lr $line $SEARCH_DIR)"); then
        echo "ENTERED"
        echo $filename
    fi
done
```

Comment: I reformatted the script. If you indent a line by four characters, it will be considered _code_ and formatted accordingly. The program will also do some syntax highlighting too. That's easier and better than trying to put back tick quotes around each line.

Comment: Thank you I was just trying to figure that out actually. Thanks for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this as `search.sh`, updating `SEARCH_DIR` as appropriate for your environment:

```
#!/bin/bash

SEARCH_DIR=some/dir/here

while read filename
do
        if [ -z "$(grep -lr $filename $SEARCH_DIR)" ]
        then
                echo $filename
        fi
done
```

Then:

```
chmod +x search.sh
./search.sh  files-i-could-not-find.txt
```

Comment: I keep getting: `./BashRemovalTool.sh: line 19: -z: command not found` and it's referring to the grep in the if statement. I will post my code above in my question.

Comment: You put parens after the `if`.  They should be square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible through `grep` and `find` commands,

```
while read -r line; do (find . -type f -exec grep -l "$line" {} \;); done < file
```

**OR**

```
while read -r line; do grep -rl "$line"; done < file
```

`-r` -->  recursive
`-l` -->  files-with-matches(Displays the filenames which contains the search string)

It will read all the filenames present inside the input file and search for the filenames which contains the readed filenames. If it found any, then it returns the corresponding filename.

Comment: He wants to search for files that _contain_ the filename, not search by filename.

Comment: Yes I want to search inside each file for file names then remove them from the list of file names that should be output. Sean is right.

Comment: Why would you use `find` over `grep -r`?

Comment: you mean this `$ while read -r line; do grep -rl "$line"; done < file`. Yep, sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're using regular parentheses instead of square brackets in your `if` statement.

The square brackets are a *test* command. You're running a test (in your case, whether a string has zero length or not. If the test is successful, the `[ ... ]` command returns an exit code of zero. The `if` statement sees that exit code and runs the `then` clause of the `if` statement. Otherwise, if an `else` statement exists, that is run instead.

Because the `[ .. ]` are actually commands, you ***must*** leave a blank space around each side.

#### Right

```
if [ -z "$string" ]
```

#### Wrong

```
if [-z "$string"]  # Need white space around the brackets
```

#### Sort of wrong

```
if [ -z $sting ]   # Won't work if "$string" is empty or contains spaces
```

By the way, the following are the same:

```
if test -z "$string"

if [ test -z "$string" ]
```

Be careful with that `grep` command. If there are spaces or newlines in the string returned, it may not do what you think it does.